# Something about php calendar

Tags: php

I am a new learner of PHP, now I want to use it to do a calendar like the following. There are something that I don't know.

1. How to get the first day of the month is sunday or another?
2. How to output all the days of the month and emphasize today?

[image]

The code:

```
<table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" bordercolor="#000000" border="1" style="width: 105px; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7"><?php echo date('F')." ".date('Y');?></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Su</td>
         <td>M</td>
         <td>Tu</td>
         <td>W</td>
         <td>Th</td>
         <td>F</td>
         <td>Sa</td>
     </tr>
     <?php
   $numrows = ceil(date('t')/7);
   for($k=1;$k<=$numrows;$k++){

         ?>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
        <?php }?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't know how to output the following days.

Comment: strotime is very powerful.  ie: date('d', strtotime("now")) will give todays day.  You can easily build from here and use javascript to animate/add css rules from here...

Comment: Adnan Shammout, thank you, i have updated my question

Answer (score 3):

### First Day of Month

```
date('d', strtotime('2012-04-01'));
```

Replace year and month with actual year and month you want to check.  Leave the `01` for the first day.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

### Output Days of Month and Emphasize Today

You can use `date()` with no second parameter to get the current time formatted however you want.  To output the days of the month, you'd need to know how you wanted them formatted, so that's up to you to figure out.  But, to get the number of days in a given month, you can use:

```
date('t')
```

That will return a number between 28 and 31, depending on how long the month is.

You really should read this:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Comment: Brad,i put the code on the above, i don't know how to write the inner loop and output the days. could you give me more details. ,many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You never need these things nowadays when http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ is available, but if you want here is the code I wrote about 10 years ago, lol :)

```
<? 
  function my_calendar($fill=array()) { 
  if (isset($_GET['y'])) $y=$_GET['y'];
  if (isset($_GET['m'])) $m=$_GET['m']; 
  if (isset($_GET['date']) AND strstr($_GET['date'],"-")) list($y,$m)=explode("-",$_GET['date']);
  if (!isset($y) OR $y < 1970 OR $y > 2037) $y=date("Y");
  if (!isset($m) OR $m < 1 OR $m > 12) $m=date("m");

  $month_stamp=mktime(0,0,0,$m,1,$y);
  $month_name=date("M",$month_stamp);
  $day_count=date("t",$month_stamp);
  $weekday=date("w",$month_stamp);
  if ($weekday==0) $weekday=7;
  $start=-($weekday-2);
  $last=($day_count+$weekday-1) % 7;
  if ($last==0) $end=$day_count; else $end=$day_count+7-$last;
  $today=date("Y-m-d");
  $prev=date('?\m=m&\y=Y',mktime (0,0,0,$m-1,1,$y));  
  $next=date('?\m=m&\y=Y',mktime (0,0,0,$m+1,1,$y));
  $i=0;
?> 
<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2> 
 <tr>
  <td colspan=7> 
   <table width="100%" border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0> 
    <tr> 
     <td align="left"><a href="<? echo $prev ?>">&lt;&lt;&lt;</a></td> 
     <td align="center"><? echo $month_name," ",$y ?></td> 
     <td align="right"><a href="<? echo $next ?>">&gt;&gt;&gt;</a></td> 
    </tr> 
   </table> 
  </td> 
 </tr> 
 <tr><td>Mon</td><td>Tue</td><td>Wed</td><td>Th</td><td>Fri</td><td>Sat</td><td>Sun</td><tr>
<? 
  for($d=$start;$d<=$end;$d++) { 
    if (!($i++ % 7)) echo " <tr>\n";
    echo '  <td align="center">';
    if ($d < 1 OR $d > $day_count) {
      echo "&nbsp";
    } else {
      $now="$y-$m-".sprintf("%02d",$d);
      if (is_array($fill) AND in_array($now,$fill)) {
        echo '<b><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?date='.$now.'">'.$d.'</a></b>'; 
      } else {
        echo $d;
      }
    } 
    echo "</td>\n";
    if (!($i % 7))  echo " </tr>\n";
  } 
?>
</table> 
<? } ?>
```

Use example

```
<? 
if (isset($_GET['date'])) echo "Date picked: ".$_GET['date'];
my_calendar(array(date("Y-m-d"))); 
?>
```

it displays Monday first though. You need to remove some lines to get it to Sunday